# How to access local variable in Anonymous class?

Tags: java

```
interface Interf {
    void m1();
}

public class Test {

    int x = 888;
    Interf f;

    public  void m2() {
         Integer x = 777;

        f = new Interf() {
            Integer x = 666;
            public void m1() {
                int x = 555;
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println(this.x);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.m2();
            t.f.m1();
    }
}
```

How can I access **x variable** with value **777** inside **m1()** method(In Anonymous class) with same name? Is it possible to access?

Answer (score 2):

No, because it is [*shadowed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#Java). But you can change the name (and no need for `Integer`, `int` will *suffice*).

```
public void m2() {
    int y = 777;

    f = new Interf() {
        int x = 666;

        public void m1() {
            int x = 555;
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(this.x);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    };
}
```

Outputs

```
555
666
777
```